# Why does the URL without "https://" in front results in a blank page?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

Let me take you to [This page with HTTPS](https://ttr.nl/thermal-printheads) and [this page without](http://ttr.nl/thermal-printheads). This is a Wordpress website and somehow the URL (and linking to) requires HTTPS:// in front, else you end up with a blank page.

Let's generalize the situation and clarify what's going on, because I don't know what's causing this. Hopefully you guys could tell me how to fix it so a URL without https:// still shows up the same page?

*<sub>Perhaps .htaccess/nginx.conf and redirecting to 'with HTTPS://' would do></sub>*

The server is running **NGINX**

My nginx.conf file:

```
    # HTTP -> HTTPS
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ttr.nl www.ttr.nl;
    return 301 https://ttr.nl$request_uri;
    }

    http {
        client_max_body_size 100m;
    }
    # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache cache
    location ~ /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced.*html$ {
        expires modified 7200s;
        add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public";
    }
    location ~ /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced.*gzip$ {
        gzip off;
        types {}
        default_type text/html;
        expires modified 7200s;
        add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public";
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    # END W3TC Page Cache cache
    # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
    location ~ \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
        expires 2592000s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public";
        add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
    }
    location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
        expires 7200s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public";
        add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
    }
    location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
        add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
    }
    # END W3TC Browser Cache
    # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
    set $w3tc_rewrite 1;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($request_uri !~ \/$) {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle)") {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "(w3tc_preview)") {
        set $w3tc_rewrite _preview;
    }
    set $w3tc_ssl "";
    if ($scheme = https) {
        set $w3tc_ssl _ssl;
    }
    set $w3tc_enc "";
    if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
        set $w3tc_enc _gzip;
    }
    set $w3tc_ext "";
    if (-f "$document_root/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_ssl$w3tc_rewrite.html$w3tc_enc") {
        set $w3tc_ext .html;
    }
    if (-f "$document_root/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_ssl$w3tc_rewrite.xml$w3tc_enc") {
        set $w3tc_ext .xml;
    }
    if ($w3tc_ext = "") {
      set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($w3tc_rewrite = 1) {
        rewrite .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_ssl$w3tc_rewrite$w3tc_ext$w3tc_enc" last;
    }
    # END W3TC Page Cache core

    #gzip via varvy.com
```

Comment: Sounds indeed like a htaccess problem. I had the same issue with my SMF forum a while ago and that was the issue.

Comment: The desired result is re-direct non https to https ? or to make both http and httpS work?  Either way, kindly post your ,htaccess file

Comment: I want my site to be using SSL only and it should work no matter if you put "https://" in front of the URL or not.

Answer (score 2):

A request for each of those URLs will go to a different port on the server.

It is probable, but not required, that the same piece of software is listening to requests on both ports. If different pieces of software (e.g. Apache and Lighttpd) are listening on different ports, then each will need to be configured to Do What You Want separately.

If it is the same piece of software, then there will be different configurations for each port (there have to be since one needs to turn SSL on and the other must not).

Those different configurations could have any number of differences, such as different DocumentRoots. OTOH, they could just as easily share large chunks of configuration data.

---

The general case of what you should do to fix this is: Configure the HTTP URL to issue a 301 redirect to the matching HTTPS URL.

The specifics of *how* you fix it will depend on how the server is set up.

Comment: I just called our server department, since I only do front-end. But during our call we noticed that -some- pages do work in both cases (with- and without https://). So I guess rather not server related, but more website related. And.. I'm unsure where to search right now. - Although, that makes this issue specific and not a general, as required on SO.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I did some further investigation, but apparently some pages only have this issue, not all pages. So I assume this is not server related, but rather Wordpress or a set-up on the server itself. But not directly related to the server configuration, such as ports.

Do you have any other thoughts that could solve this issue?